# Angular JS code is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea why when I do an AngularJS tutorial that it doesn't work in my browser. I'm new to AngularJS. Any insights would be great. I have 3 files.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>First Angular App</title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="core.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="main_div" ng-app='my_ang_app' ng-controller='first_div'>
       {{message}}
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('my_ang_app', []);
```

core.js:

```
app.controller('first_div', function ($scope) {
     $scope.message="Hello world from angular";
    });
```

When I preview it in the browser it shows {{message}}

Comment: What are the errors in console?

Comment: Check your file paths.

Comment: Your Angular code and corresponding html are syntactically and semantically correct. The only things I can surmise that would be wrong are your file paths or file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the javascript files you refered are loaded correctly and its always better if you refer them after loading the view. Something like below,

```
  <body>
    <div id="main_div" ng-app='my_ang_app' ng-controller='first_div'>
    {{message}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Here is the [`working App`](http://plnkr.co/edit/OW6LWxShcW127r5lRxkA?p=preview)

Comment: I moved them to the bottom and its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not linking to the proper javascript file paths. Try to inspect element to see if you have any 404 errors.